# Random black screen at startup before BIOS message

Tags: boot, memory, bios

After looking for similar case, which I haven't found, I'm resigned to ask for help.

Time to time, my computer starts with a black screen without a BIOS message, just a black screen. I hear the fans running. I know it's not a display issue cause I can't access my SSH. I just push the reset button, then it start normally and works nicely.

Here's my config (Windows 10) :

- Mainboard: Asus TUF gaming X570-plus wi-fi (last bios update from asus - 2019/11/26)
- CPU : AMD Ryzen 3700x (last chipset from amd - 16/1/2020)
- Ram : HyperX Fury DDR4 Kit 2x16GB 32GB 3200MHz CL16 (a2 / b2 slots on MB)
- PS : Seasonic G-650, 650W
- GC : Sapphire rx580

The motherboard is using the XMP profile in order to get the 3200MHZ. I never turned it off, because I use WOL packets. The black screen has never occured on reboot. The PC has never crashed except for one time when I used an AMD beta driver. The fast boost mode has been disabled both in windows 10 and BIOS. Except for fast boost mode, WOL and XMP, nothing has been changed in the motherboard configuration.

And that's all I can tell...
Thanks for those looking for my problem!

Comment: Just run it with single RAM and see if the issue repeats. Also try with another single RAM as well and see if it repeats. It appears that for some reasons when it's a cold boot possibly firmware has a problem detecting something or initializing it and it sort of stalls.

Comment: I'll try, thing is, it happens mainly when the pc has been shutdown for a while, it's random and scarcely. Very difficult to diagnose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I set manually the ram to 3200MHz thanks to the Ryzen DRAM calculator tool. Yet the issue happened sometimes after. But for now, it has been 1 month without issue. I guess problem solve, but I'm not sure why since I didn't update my bios since...

EDIT : Problem solved by bios update, I guess there was some compability problem with my ram (it wasn't in the motherboard vendor list).
Thank you all !

Answer (score 1):

Modern RAM requires a complex calibration process that's done before pretty much any of the UEFI starts, due to RAM running so fast that unique characteristics of the motherboard have to be accounted for.  [Details](https://github.com/librecore-org/librecore/wiki/Understanding-DDR-Memory-Training).

If this never completes or fails, you won't see the UEFI screen.  Issues with one or more RAM sticks, or motherboard problems, could interfere.  Other things are power supply issues, electromagnetic interference (but it'd have to be pretty strong), or possibly temperature extremes.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem about a year ago.
It turns out that it was the BIOS battery needed replacement.
Maybe worth a try.

Comment: Well, the motherboard is fresh new but i'll give a try!

Comment: So I tried, it didn't work, I still had the problem after saving changes in mobo then reset. Thx though!

Comment: It worked for my motherboard. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related to [this issue](https://community.amd.com/thread/244440) by any chance? That issue is about AMD CPUs having a problem with more than 2 CPU-temperature-sensing programs and crashing to a black screen with fans at default speeds. In that issue (which I had), the reset and power buttons don't even work, but there was one user who reported that his still worked, so it might be variable.

It also sounds familiar when you say you never turn off the computer, and it's never happened on reboot, so I'm assuming it's happened when waking up from sleep. That's how this issue has behaved too (including for me).

Check it out and see if it matches.